# Finding same objects assigned to a string in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I am not sure if I expressed myself correctly with the title but I will try to be more specific here.

**What I have:** 
An *arraylist* with **clients/customers.**
An *arraylist* with **phone numbers** assigned to the clients/customers.

**My Client class:** 
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Clients implements Comparable<Clients> {

    private String name;
    private String address;

    public ArrayList<Share> shareList = new ArrayList<Share>();

    private PhoneBook phoneBook = new PhoneBook(); 

    public Clients(String name, String address) {

        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }


    public void addPhoneDescription(String description) {
        phoneBook.addPhoneDescription(description);
    }

    public void addPhoneNumber(String number) {
        phoneBook.addPhoneNumber(number);
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public PhoneBook getPhoneBook() {
        return phoneBook;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Clients c = (Clients) obj;
        return this.name.equals(c.name);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result;

        result = ("\n" + "Name: " + this.getName() + "\n" + "Address: "
                + this.getAddress() + "\n" + "Phone description: " + this
                .getPhoneBook());

        return result;
    }

    public int compareTo(Clients other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.name);

    }

}
```

This is my **PhoneBook class** consisting of set/get methods:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhoneBook {

    private ArrayList<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> phoneDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addPhoneDescription(String description) {
        phoneDescription.add(description);
    }

    public void addPhoneNumber(String number) { // Add the phone number to the numbersList

        numbersList.add(number);

    }

    public String toString(){
        return numbersList.toString() + phoneDescription.toString();
    }


}
```

What I want to achieve: So if I create lets say 3 clients and 2 of them have the same numbers I want to print out those 2 clients with the number they share/have in common and so on. I have create a method over at my **Program** class:

```
public void findDuplicatedNumbers() {

        // method that looks for duplicated numbers that clients have

        ArrayList<Integer> sNumber = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> duplicateNumber = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < (clientList.get(i).getPhoneBook().size); k++) {
                if (sNumber.contains(clientList.get(i).getPhoneBook().get(k).getNumber())) {
                    if (duplicateNumber.contains(clientList.get(i).getPhoneBook().get(k).getNumber())) {

                } else {
                        // adds to duplicateNumber arrayList
                        duplicateNumber.add(clientList.get(i).getPhoneBook().get(k).getNumber());
                    }
                } else {
                    // adds to sNumber arrayList
                    sNumber.add(clientList.get(i).getPhoneBook().get(k).getNumber());
                }
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicateNumber.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Phone number: " + duplicateNumber.get(i) + " is share with these clients: ");
            for (int k = 0; k < clientList.size(); k++) {
                for (int p = 0; p < (clientList.get(p).getPhoneBook().size()); p++) {
                    if (duplicateNumber.get(i) == clientList.get(k).getPhoneBook().get(p).getNumber()) {
                        System.out.println(clientList.get(k).getName() + ", ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puh .. quiet a lot of code for a simple task. KISS (keep it simple):

```
public void findDuplicatedNumbers() {
    Map<String, Set<Client> > duplicates = 
       new HashMap<String, Set<Client> >();
    Set<String> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<String>();

    for(Client client : clientList) {
         PhoneBook phoneBook = client.getPhoneBook();
         phoneNumbers.addAll(phoneBook.getNumberList());
    }

    for(String phoneNumber : phoneNumbers) {
       Set<Client> clients = findClientsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

       if(clients.size() > 1)
           duplicates.put(phoneNumber, clients);
    }

    for(Entry<String, Set<Client> entry : duplicates.entrySet()) {

          System.out.println("phonenumber " +  entry.getKey() + " is dubplicated / is share with these clients:");
          for(Client client : entry.getValue()) {
             System.out.println(client.getName());
          }

    }
}
protected Set<Client> findClientsByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<Client>();

    for(Client client : clientList ) {
       List<String> phoneNumbers = client.getPhonebook().getNumberList();
       if(phoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber)) {
          clients.add(client);
       }
    }
    return clients;
}
```

This is not only cleaner structured and implements an additional interface for finding clients by number but also more performance in most cases.
Just be clean about what you want to do: If you want to store a list of unique objects, it is one of the Set - implementations. If you want to store something by a key, use a Map - implementation.

Comment: I kind of understand your code but I do not really need the find clients by number. In my program (main class) I have a switch case scenario so when the user presses a number the method findDuplicatedNumbers runs. Still experiencing a little difficulties. Mind telling me how to do it? @Peter

Comment: But that's exactly what you do: checking the phonenumbers if they are assigned multiple times. Your println shows your output. I will modify the code above to make it more clear.

Comment: To put it more clear: You compare the phonenumber of a client to the phonenumbers of all other clients. If it exist in the other clients list and the client found is not equal, it is a duplicate. So you are indeed searching all clients for a given phonenumber, but are only interested in those phonenumbers, which are assigned to multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PhoneBook {

    private ArrayList<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> phoneDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addPhoneDescription(String description) {
        phoneDescription.add(description);
    }

    public void addPhoneNumber(String number) { // Add the phone number to the numbersList

        numbersList.add(number);

    }

    public String toString(){
        return numbersList.toString() + phoneDescription.toString();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> findDuplicatedNumbers() {
        ArrayList<String> dupes = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.sort(numbersList);
        Iterator<String> iter = numbersList.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            String next = iter.next();
            if(iter.hasNext() && next == iter.next()) {
                dupes.add(next);
            }
        }

        return dupes;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do understand what you do but I get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Program.findDuplicatedNumbers(Program.java:253)

Comment: Also you have the findDuplicatedNumbers over at the PhoneBook class and I want it at the Program class. :/